# Why are object_id in photo table(fql) and object_id through graph api different?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I queried a page with due permissions for its feed. There was a post with three photos. The response json was:

```
{
        "id": "some_id", 
        "from": {
          "category": "Tv show", 
          "name": "some_name", 
          "id": "some_id"
        }, 
        "message": "New post with 3 photos", 
        "picture": "some_link", 
        "link": "some_link", 
        "icon": "some_link", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "some_link"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "some_link"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Public", 
          "value": "EVERYONE", 
          "friends": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": ""
        }, 
        "type": "photo", 
        "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
        "object_id": "some_id", 
        "created_time": "2014-02-05T07:06:22+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-02-05T07:06:35+0000", 
        "likes": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "some_id", 
              "name": "some_name"
            }
          ], 
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "after": "MTgyNDY2NjQ1MjM4MTc5", 
              "before": "MTgyNDY2NjQ1MjM4MTc5"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "some_id", 
              "from": {
                "category": "Tv show", 
                "name": "some_name", 
                "id": "some_id"
              }, 
              "message": "With a comment and a like on it", 
              "can_remove": true, 
              "created_time": "2014-02-05T07:06:35+0000", 
              "like_count": 0, 
              "user_likes": false
            }
          ], 
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "after": "MQ==", 
              "before": "MQ=="
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

Firstly, I only got one object_id, whereas the post contained 3 photos. The object_id was of a single photo. I also queried through fql for object_id for that photo in photo table and the object_ids were not matching. Why is it so? What does object_id mean in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The Object ID for Posts will be different to the Object ID of the photos used in the post, as they are effectively different representations of the same thing. The `id` will be the ID of the page post, and the `object_id` will be the Album ID of the uploaded photos.

Try calling `/{object_id}/photos` to get the list of photos in the post.

A good way to test what each `object_id` represents is to go to `http://www.facebook.com/{object_id}` to see where it goes. It will either go to a page, post, album / media set, photo or an error page.